# Какие есть способы сделать результат в одну строку?

Tags: python

Например:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    print(i)
```

Вывод будет:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Какие способы есть, чтобы сделать вывод в 1 строку (кроме `end=''`), спасибо

Answer (score 6):

```
print('1 2 3 4')
print(1, 2, 3, 4)
print(*range(1, 5))
print(' '.join([str(i) for i in range(1, 5)]))
[ __import__('sys').stdout.write(str(i) + '\x20') for i in range(1, 5)]
```